# Can I create a mobx computed inside a React render function to use like useMemo()?

Tags: mobx, mobx-react

I'm wondering how to go about using a mobx observable inside a `useMemo` hook. I know I could pass all possibly dependencies to the hook, but that could get kind of messy:

```
const MyComponent = observer(() => {
  const people = useGetPeople();
  const peopleFormatted = useMemo(() => {
    return people.map(person => person.fullName);
  },[ ...? ]);
});
```

I can't easily make every person's `firstName` be a dependency of `useMemo`. I'd think I could extract the functionality to a computed ... but I feel like this won't work:

```
const MyComponent = observer(() => {
  const people = useGetPeople();
  const peopleFormatted = computed(() => {
    return people.map(person => person.fullName);
  });
});
```

I feel like it will confuse mobx to create a computed inside a reaction that the reaction must depend on.

I know I could extract the computed to each person but I don't feel like that's a solution that matches every use case.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `const people = useGetPeople();` is an observable array of some sort of people objects...

```js
const peopleFormatted = computed(() => {
    return people.map(person => person.fullName);
  }).get(); //note .get()
```

Should work fine inside the observer function body. See https://mobx.js.org/computeds-with-args.html#2-close-over-the-arguments

What is confusing me is `useGetPeople();`

That typically means you are using react's state api for managing state and reactions. ie: `useState`, etc.

Without seeing what `useGetPeople()` does under the hood, it's hard to give a concrete answer.

Comment: I actually ended up asking this question on the mobx gitter (I think) and got the same answer. You can use a computed inside a react render function that is observed.